# Remove dev/sit code when grunt build is for prod

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I want to add a temporary javascript code in our application in dev environment but when we are about to make a build for production, that code will be ignored and not included in the newly built code.

```
var userLoggedIn = isUserLogged();

/* ignore-for-dev-only-begin */
  userLoggedIn = true;
/* ignore-for-dev-only-end */

if (userLoggedIn) {
  // do whatever you need to do
}
```

If you see, I'll be able to login with any user account(even wrong passwords) and since I am in development env, it will always allow me to use the application. Once I make a new build for production, that code should be removed.

How is that done in Grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are packages such us [grunt-devcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-devcode) and [grunt-strip-code](https://github.com/nuzzio/grunt-strip-code)

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't aware those exists! Thanks :)